# Renew JSESSIONID after success login

Tags: session, jboss, liferay, hook, jsessionid

I want that when a user login correctly the JSESSIONID ID is changed.

I have my own Hook to deal with autologin with the AutologinTokenClient library (first_hook), and another Hook to verify if the user is an administrator, redirect it to the administration panel (second_hook).

My config:

```
JBOSS: jboss-eap-6.4
Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.2.10 EE GA1
```

I have tried to add the tag in the login.jsp that I have modified in the first Hook (first_hook). But it is always the same ID.

```
<% @ page session = "false"%>
```

In the first_hook I have a postlogin class with some methods, I tried to put the following function, but every time I execute it I get out of the session and I have to re-login.

```
private void renewSessionID (HttpServletRequest request)
{
    LOG.info ("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
    HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession (true);
    LOG.info("OLD_SESSION: "+oldSession.getId ());

    Enumeration attrNames = oldSession.getAttributeNames ();
    Properties props = new Properties ();

    if (attrNames != null)
    {
        while (attrNames.hasMoreElements ())
        {
            String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement ();
            props.put (key, oldSession.getAttribute (key));
        }

        // Invalidating previous session
        oldSession.invalidate ();
        // Generate new session
        HttpSession newSession = request.getSession (true);
        attrNames = props.keys ();

        while (attrNames.hasMoreElements ())
        {
            String key = (String) attrNames.nextElement ();
            newSession.setAttribute (key, props.get (key));
        }

        LOG.info ("NEW_SESSION: "+newSession.getId ());
    }
}
```

And the error is the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000043: Can not create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession (Request.java:2649)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession (Request.java:2382)
```

I have also tried separately to add the following lines of text to the portal-ext.properties file, but it does not change anything:

```
session.enable.phishing.protection = true
session.phishing.protected.attributes = CAS_LOGIN, HTTPS_INITIAL, LAST_PATH, OPEN_ID_CONNECT_SESSION
```

---

Any idea?

Comment: You're giving us the code in question. Great. But where in the call chain is it executed? In a filter? A portlet? And note: A portal's full HTML page is composed out of many different JSPs - just that one JSP does declare to work without a session, doesn't mean that the whole page works without - in fact, the session might be started elsewhere, completely outside of JSP code. And finally (but I didn't validate this) I thought that Liferay does create a new session already when someone logs in, copying relevant attributes to the new session. Can you confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add logic in your own code to provide this. You are only required to enable this feature in your properties file.

```
session.enable.phishing.protection = true
```

That is all that is to it. You will not however be able to detect this like that, as the session will be renewed after the control is transferred back to Liferay, which means you would need a second hook after login to verify that the ID was changed ( or you can simply check in your browser's cookie view).

About your own implementation of this feature:

Javadocs for request#getSession:

> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if
>   there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
>
> If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this
>   method returns null.
>
> To make sure the session is properly maintained, you must call this
>   method before the response is committed. If the container is using
>   cookies to maintain session integrity and is asked to create a new
>   session when the response is committed, an IllegalStateException is
>   thrown.

Comment: Hi. That was the first thing I tried before changing all the previous things, I added that line to the portal-ext.properties file, and rebooted the server. But it did nothing, not change the ID, or change any parameters. And the session was the same before and after the login.

Comment: did you check if your portal.properties is including your portal-ext.properties?